# post_exists returning 0 if title contain special characters

Tags: theme-development, wp-title, get-the-title

I am using the below code:

```
$title = get_the_title($result->post_id);

if ( 0 === post_exists( $title ) ) {
$title = 'Document Id: '.$result->post_id .' (Deleted)';
}
```

But it's returning 0 if post title contains special characters.
I also tried using

```
$title = esc_attr(get_the_title($result->post_id));
```

but no luck.

Comment: What characters specifically are you using in your post titles?

Comment: Mostly characters are  `– : * , . & `

Comment: Try 
``` 
$title = get_the_title($result->post_id); echo $title; 
``` 
and post the result here so I can see how the data is being stored in the DB

Comment: Activities &#8211; More Than Games

Answer (score 2):

Looks like WP is using HTML entity encoding on the special characters, you need to parse the title using the `html_entity_decode()` function like so.

```
$title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title($result->post_id));

if ( 0 === post_exists( $title ) ) {
$title = 'Document Id: '.$result->post_id .' (Deleted)';
}
```

I am not sure if the post exists function decodes the characters but I am going to assume it does, let me know if you are still getting a 0 though

Comment below any questions!

Comment: This doesn't work. It still returning 0.

Comment: Works for me, thank you.